# What are some good sources to know more about the Buddha and his teachings

Tags: the-buddha, texts

When I was going through difficult face my life, I read little bit about the Buddha's thoughts and it really changed my life. When I started to think from his perspective, I explored a new way of looking at Life which was amazing.

I want to know more about his philosophy towards `LIFE`. I tried `Wiki` and other article over the internet, But it doesn't satisfies me. Can anybody suggest me any good source like any book English or Hindi.

Comment: http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/ritepath.pdf

Comment: http://www.wisebrain.org/HouseholderPractice.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some meta-topics tagged [book-of-the-month](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-the-month) in some of which people suggest various books they'd like to read or recommend reading:

- [Choosing a book for book of the month club?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1500/254)
- [Choosing a book for Book of the Month [June]](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1574/254)
- [Choosing a book for Book of the Month [July]](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1620/254)

Answer (score 1):

Some introductory online resources are listed in the [Useful resources section at the top of the Help page](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help).